# Make action bar bigger

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-appcompat

I have the following gradle `AppCompat` and activity definitions:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'

<activity
    android:name="MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>
```

Action bar currently looks like this:
[image]

I'd like to make title and subtitle fonts bigger and also adjust an image size, how can I do that?
After some searching I've found out I should start with defining a custom `Toolbar` in activity XML like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/background_material_dark"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>
```

But once I put that code inside my activity I get the following rendering error:
[image]

So I'm kind of lost here, can someone explain what's going on and what should I do?

**UPD**

Following some tutorial I've tried this:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyTheme.ActionBarStyle" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
        <item name="android:subtitleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.Subtitle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.Subtitle" parent="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:textColor">#FF0000</item>
    </style>
```

And now both title and subtitle are just not visible. I suspect I should use some other parent instead of `@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar` but I have no idea which exactly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the style Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.

```
<!-- Toolbar styles -->
<item name="toolbarStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar</item>
```

Comment: Where exactly should I put this line?

Comment: If you are using Android Studio, you can set styles by pressing CTRL .
It manages values.xml file.